# SUMAR DATOS EN LINUX

Tags: linux, centos, shell-script

Como puedo hacer para restar los valores de la cantidad de entradas vendidas por evento a la cantidad total de butacas de cada tribuna del evento para saber las butacas disponibles de ese evento

```
function menu
{
  echo "MENU PRINCIPAL"
  echo "1. Consultas"
  echo "2. Ingresar nueva venta"
  echo "0. Salir"
}

Opcion=1
while [ $Opcion -ne 0 ]
do
  clear
  menu
  read -p "Ingrese una opcion: " Opcion
  case $Opcion in
    1) sh MenuConsultas.sh
    ;;
    2) sh IngresarVenta.sh
    ;;
    0) echo "Hasta luego"
    ;;
    *) echo "Opcion incorrecta"
      Opcion=1
      read -p "Presione enter para continuar" enter
      ;;
  esac
done

function ingresar
{
  echo "Ingrese la fecha del evento: "
  read fecha
  echo "Ingrese el nombre del evento: "
  read nombre
  echo "Ingrese la ubicacion: "
  read ubicacion
  echo "Ingrese el valor: "
  read valor
  echo "Ingrese C.I: "
  read ci

  echo "$fecha - $nombre - $ubicacion - $valor - $ci" >> EntradasVendidas.txt
}

echo "Ingrese 1 para registrar una nueva venta. Ingrese 2 para volver al menu principal"

case $opcion in
  1) ingresar
  ;;
  2) sh MenuPrincipal.sh
  ;;
  *) echo "Opcion incorrecta. Se volvera al menu principal"
  sh MenuPrincipal.sh
  ;;
esac

function menu
{
  echo "MENU CONSULTAS"
  echo "1. Entradas vendidas por evento"
  echo "2. Entradas disponibles por evento"
  echo "0. Volver al menu principal"
}

Opcion=1
while [ $Opcion -ne 0 ]
do
  clear
  menu
  read -p "Ingrese una opcion: " Opcion
  case $Opcion in
    1) sh EntradasVendidasPorEvento.sh
    ;;
    2) sh EntradasDisponiblesPorEvento.sh
    ;;
    0) sh MenuPrincipal.sh
    ;;
    *) echo "Opcion incorrecta"
      Opcion=1
      read -p "Presione enter para continuar" enter
      ;;
  esac
done

echo "Ingrese el nombre del evento: "
read evento
echo "Cantidad de entradas vendidas para $evento: "
grep -i "$evento" EntradasVendidas.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: butacas=50; vendidas=22; total=$(($butacas-$vendidas));

Answer (score 0):

Se necesitaría ingresar por variable o en un fichero el numero total que tendremos antes de realizar la consulta.

Tenemos un fichero donde almacenamos aquellas que vendemos:

```
EntradasVendidas.txt
```

Generaremos una variable o un fichero en el que tendremos el total de entradas para cada evento:

*Fichero:*

```
EntradasTotales.txt
```

*Variable:*

```
TOTALES=50
```

Tendremos que hacer lo siguiente para realizar la resta, definiendo los valores con variables:

```
VENDIDAS=`grep -i "$evento" EntradasVendidas.txt | wc -l`
TOTALES=`grep -i "$evento" EntradasTotales.txt | wc -l`

DISP=`expr ${TOTALES} - ${VENDIDAS}`

echo "Tenemos un total de ${DISP} entradas disponibles para ${evento}
```

En caso de tener las totales en una variable en vez de por fichero, tendríamos que cambiar simplemente esa linea.